# Application of Borel Cantelli lemma 2

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Suppose that a monkey sits in front of a computer and starts hammering keys randomly on the keyboard. Show that the famous Shakespeare monologue starting "All the worlds a stage" will eventually appear (with probability 1) in its entirety on the screen, although our monkey is not particularly known for its good taste in literature. You can make reasonable additional assumptions to form a probability model; for example, you can assume that the monkey picks characters uniformly at random on the keyboard and that the successive keystrokes are independent.

In this problem I have tried to show that that particular sentence as an event $A_n$ will be less than $\infty$ means $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n} < \infty$ happens almost surely which is the first BC lemma. But how to show this I am not getting

Comment: If I'm not wrong, uniformly at random might mean the probability of pressing a button could be $\Bbb P(A_n)=\frac1{\text{ no. of buttons}},\forall n,$ but those events are independent, right? So you could maybe apply the converse statement, if $(A_n)_n$ is a sequence of independent events and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb P(A_n)=\infty,$ then $\Bbb P(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup A_n)=1$ and $x\in \lim\sup_{n\to\infty}A_n\iff x\in A_n$ for infinitely many $n\in\Bbb N$. Independence isn't the assumption of the Borel-Cantelli lema, only its converse statement.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need BC here. That's more for sequences of events. Here, you have a fixed event.

Consider sequential block so 16 letters (the number of letters in the phrase, including spaces). In a given block, the probability of seeing the correct phrase is $p := 1/N^{16}$, where $N$ is the number of keys. This is due to your assumptions on uniformity and independence.

Now, what's the probability that you *don't* see this in the first $k$ blocks. The blocks are disjoint, so the probabilities are independent. Thus, the probability is $(1 - p)^k$. Indeed, you're just asking for $k$ independent events, each with probability $1 - p$ to happen.

Now, clearly $(1 - p)^k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, since $p \ne 0$. So this probability becomes smaller than any threshold, if we're allowed to take $k$ larger and larger. More precisely, let $q := \Pr(\text{never see phrase})$. We have shown that $q \le (1 - p)^k$---in fact, this is "never see before 16$k$ letter", but this is a stronger claim, so the inequality is the correct way around.
Letting $k \to \infty$, we see that
$$ q \le \limsup_{k \to \infty} (1 - p)^k = 0. $$
Thus, $q = 0$, as desired.

---

Incidentally, you can get tighter bounds on the decay in terms of the number of letters seen using *renewal theory*. Basically, if the first letter isn't "A", then you don't need to wait for a new block. You have to *very carefully* set up the locations of the blocks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** "All the worlds a stage" has $\ell$ symbols. Imagine dividing the infinite sequence of letters typed by the monkey into disjoint blocks of length $\ell$. Let $A_n$ be the event that the $n^{th}$ block is equal to "All the worlds a stage." Since the events $A_n$ are independent, you can apply the second Borel-Cantelli lemma to the sequence $(A_n)_{n\ge 1}$ to conclude that with probability one, infinitely many $A_n$ will occur. Just show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)=\infty$; it is a very easy sum in this case. In particular, $A_n$ will occur at least once.

Comment: This seems a bit overkill to me, don't you think? Sure, Borel--Cantelli *can* be used to say that one of a sequence of iid, non-null events happens almost surely. But, I think you should emphasise that Borel--Cantelli is stronger than needed. An elementary approach, such as the one I described, is to be preferred. It's nice that you've written how to do it will BC---nice to see!---but it should be one of these "Here's how you can, but don't" SE answers. Of course, explain *why* one shouldn't (simplicity, etc), unlike most of those answerers who just say "don't" but don't explain why

Comment: My answer doesn’t need to address any of that, because your answer already handled it sufficiently well :). Also, maybe the goal was not “answer the question as simply as possible,” but was instead to “get practice applying BC2”.

Comment: Fair points! =D